# Inserting into mysql from android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new to android development. As part of a bigger project I want to insert data from an android device to a web-server. So I did some research and articles like [The article from androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) and [this article from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/289191/Send-and-Recive-Parameter-with-Android-To-Mysql-PH) were really helpful in trying to develop a test-app which inserts in to a mysql db, which is residing at a remote web-server.

Here is my android code

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxxxx.in/installment.php");
        try{
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", editTextCustomer.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("amount", editTextAmount.getText().toString()));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
         }
     }
    else { 
        Toast.makeText(PayBillActivity.this, "Internet Access, Denied!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Here is the php code

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['amount'])) {

   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $amount = $_POST['amount'];

   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","passwd","db_name");

    // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO installment (name, amount) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[amount]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($sql) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Installment made successfully";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        echo $result;
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    //$amount = 1000;
    //echo $amount;
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

when I run the app, I am getting this "NetworkOnMainThreadException" exception and as a result no rows are being added. But its working perfect with HTML POST.

Can anyone tell me where the problem is in my code?
Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Android does not allow/strongly discourage you from doing Network related processes in the Main thread. Network related processes may delay the application for a long time if executed in the Main thread. It is encouraged that you put such processes in an Asynchronous Thread.

Comment: If you put "NetworkOnMainThreadException" into the search box on this site you will get 342 results. That should help you

Answer (score 2):

I think if you spent the time you did on posting this question into google you may have got some good answers...  Just to complete this question

There are two options available with you, either you can add a line of code and allow network operation on main thread, but its very very bad for your app and also as a coding style.

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

The longer option is to redesign the code to have the network operations performed in a separate thread.  This is both good for the app and you will learn how to work on a multi-threaded program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use that strict or take it manually out of main..

Just use a smart premade lib and it is making all for you !

Download : http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Note: And this lib is even using gzip to compress requests :)